# Create-React-App : Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./locale"

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, create-react-app

I've a project initialised with Create-React-App.

All works a-OK if I...

`npm run start` and view on http://localhost:3000

or

`npm run build && serve -s build` and view on http://localhost:5000

However after I deploy to an s3 bucket with...

`npm run build && aws s3 sync build/ s3://${DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET}`

...I go to the s3 url and get a blank screen with this error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./locale"

I think it might be something to do with moment.js - although it's not a dependency I've added.

Looking in my node_modules I can see the the moment.js is at version 2.18.1, which I think rules out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672848/7925744)

I'm not sure how to debug this issue, so any help appreciated.

Don't know if this will help, but my current package.json is as below.

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^1.19.0",
    "antd": "^2.13.4",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13",
    "recompose": "^0.25.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding momentJS as an explicit dependency, to see if it fixes your issue? As to why it's being used and is missing, it might have to do with your building process, which is not detailed in your question. It could be used as a dependency by one of the packages you're using, and then left out during your build.

Comment: How annoying - yes adding moment as a dependency has fixed it - Cheers @jaxx

Comment: The answer I gave didn't help at all? I was hoping, for your sake, that you wouldn't have to add this dependency after commenting out that one line in the production build config.

Comment: Well, although it's not required right now (I've just started the project) I've  realised that I will actually end up using momentjs, so I popped it in and all it all works.

Comment: Also, beinng a React/JS/NPM noobie, I wasn't sure how you go about commenting out a line of code in node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same problem when I install ant design dependency to use it. I got the same error message

> Error: Cannot find module "./locale"

Then I install moment and then uninstall it and this bug is also gone with it.

```
npm install moment@2.24.0

npm uninstall moment
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the way react-scripts handles project building, I found this interesting snippet of code in the `/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js` file that comes with create-react-app (this is the Webpack config file for the prod build).

```
// Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
// by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
// solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
// https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
// You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
```

You probably want to either import specific locales, if you use any, which doesn't appear to be the case, or comment out that line otherwise.