# Create react app Error: Cannot find module './locale'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app

I bootstrapped my application with *create-react-app* and when I run my app it compiles with warnings and it throws errors on the browser.

*Error while compiling*

```
./node_modules/rc-picker/node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale/locales.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './locale' in '/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/node_modules/rc-picker/node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale'
```

*Error on browser*

```
Error: Cannot find module './locale'
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../node_modules/moment/src/lib/moment/moment.js
node_modules/moment/src/lib/moment/moment.js:1
__webpack_require__
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../node_modules/moment/src/moment.js
node_modules/moment/src/moment.js:1
__webpack_require__
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../node_modules/rc-picker/es/generate/moment.js
node_modules/rc-picker/es/generate/moment.js:1
__webpack_require__
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../node_modules/antd/es/calendar/index.js
node_modules/antd/es/calendar/index.js:1
__webpack_require__
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../node_modules/antd/es/index.js
node_modules/antd/es/index.js:3
__webpack_require__
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../src/components/AuthPage/loginPage.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:313:62
__webpack_require__
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../src/App.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:127:88
__webpack_require__
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../src/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1595:62
__webpack_require__
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1737:18
__webpack_require__
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
/Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/pizza/Yummi-fend/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:65
```

*Package.json*

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "antd": "^4.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "yup": "^0.28.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried researching and its an error originating from **moment-js** yet I'm not using that module and it is also not installed.

What could be the problem?

Comment: If you are not using moment, then run `yarn remove moment` or `npm uninstall moment`

Comment: @Redline Thanks. I have tried this and it hasn't worked for me

Comment: @KinaraNyakaru Try this. Remove node-modules folder, I mean delete it and then do an npm install, See if it works

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Sorry I forgot to state that I tried that before and It didn't work

Comment: @KinaraNyakaru This error is a latest one and is coming due to the update in moment library.Follow the steps provided in the answer to solve it. Do please rate if it helps :)

Comment: @KinaraNyakaru Hope your project runs perfect now. If you wish you can accept  my   Answer by clicking on tick sign which is visible to only you so that other developers can also benefit from it  :) Thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The reason this happens is because **moment** has released the new version from **2.24.0 to 2.25.0**

**Perform the following Steps to solve this issue :**

**Step 1:** **change the versions** (In your case just add the **"moment":"2.24.0"** to your dependencies in your **package.json** since I don't see it present in your package.json)

```
"moment": "2.24.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.28",
```

**Step 2:** If you are using **yarn** please add resolutions in your package.json file like this

```
"dependencies" {
"moment": "2.24.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.28"
},
"resolutions": {
"moment": "2.24.0"
},
```

For more information about this issue go to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4505

Comment: It seems like the version 2.25.2 was addressing this issue. So a downgrade to 2.24.0 is not required anymore.

Comment: @Matt Weber : So far downgrade has worked for lots of lots of developers. On 4th May  2.25.2 version has come up, still with pretty less downloads. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moment.js/

Answer (score 0):

Change in package.json :

```
"moment": "2.25.1",
```

to

```
"moment": "2.24.0",
```

then run on terminal: **npm install**

Answer (score 0):

Moment Released new version that breaks application,

as in your case there is no moment in package.json, if you simply add this to your package

`moment: "2.24.0"`

and run npm install it will add this moment package and resolve your issue,

otherwise you can try this cammand

```
npm install --save --save-exact moment@2.24.0
```

it will automatically add this package to your package.json with this specific version

i hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

New moment 2.25.x versions have been released and the latest version should fix this issue.

It seems like the version [2.25.2](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#2252) was addressing this issue. So a downgrade to 2.24.0 is not required anymore.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer